# ThreeJS Directional Light not working on Electron build

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, electron, electron-builder

I am currently developing our Typescript application into an Electron application using *electron-builder*. This part of the application is the display of a 3D model separated into different meshes with several colours available depending on previous results. In a "native" build without electron, the 3D model is well displayed with all lights. However when I use the electron-builder function to create the package I face a strange issue : the 3D model is well displayed but there are no light.

I have this part of the code where I call the directionalLight

```js
            <SHeart3D>
                <Canvas gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: false }}>
                    <directionalLight intensity={0.9} />
                    <directionalLight intensity={0.7} position={[0.8, 1, 1]} />
                    <directionalLight intensity={0.5} position={[-0.8, -1, -1]} />
                    <directionalLight intensity={0.3} position={[2, 0, 0]} />
                    <directionalLight intensity={0.3} position={[-2, 0, 0]} />
                    <Suspense fallback={null}>
                        <Heart3DCreation
                            ladResults={ladResults}
                            cxResults={cxResults}
                            rcaResults={rcaResults}
                            setCurrentCoronary={setCurrentCoronary}
                            medicalProps={medicalProps}
                            isMedicalReportValidationDisplayed={isMedicalReportValidationDisplayed}
                            displayMuscle={displayMuscle}
                            ffrAvailable={ffrAvailable}
                        />
                    </Suspense>
                    <CameraControls ref={cameraControls} />
                </Canvas>
            </SHeart3D>
```

I already tried to change the *preserveDrawingBuffer* to false but it does not change anything.

Comment: I tried with ambientLight but all I get is a different kind of lighting but it is still darker than the normal version.